# send mail with attachement php

Tags: php, phpmailer

my code not working

when the email arrives, the contents of the file are in base64, not in the correct format.

How to correct this?

my code

```
$headers = 'From: ' .     "$from\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . "$from\r\n";


$file = $arquivo['tmp_name'];
$originalFile = $arquivo['name'];
$file_size = filesize($file);
$handle = fopen($file, "rb");
$anexo = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$anexo = chunk_split(base64_encode($anexo));

// a random hash será necessário para separar conteúdos diversos a serem enviados
$separator = md5(time());

// Define o retorno de carro a ser utilizado
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// main header (multipart mandatory)
$headers = "From: $from" . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol . $eol;


// message
$msg .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$msg .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"" . $eol;
$msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol . $eol;
$msg .= $mensagemHTML . $eol . $eol;

// attachment
$msg .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$msg .= "Content-Type: ".$arquivo["type"]."; name=".$arquivo['name']." \n" . $eol;
$msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
$msg .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$arquivo['name']." " . $eol . $eol;
$msg .= $anexo . $eol . $eol;
$msg .= "--" . $separator . "--";


$envio = mail($emaildestinatario, $assunto, $msg, $headers);
```

this attchament

[image]

[image]

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: you tag this with 'phpmailer' but dont use it, you really should, its much better than 'raw' php's mail() https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: @KirkBeard i using php 7

Comment: @KirkBeard yes, i read,I tried to implement and only give error. Only works with mail (), I just need to know a solution for this encryption